Solana testing tool
I want to write contracts in rust using Anchor. And do testing in rust.
I have seen examples mostly with testing done in JS/TS. My intention is to go full-rust with contracts + FE + BE
Is it possible?

This is possible,
I have a few guides and examples you can use,

https://solana.com/docs/clients/rust some of the crates you might need to do this in the official guides

Doing it with anchor, check out the anchor rust client https://docs.rs/anchor-client/latest/anchor_client/

Check out the Ellipsis Labs V1 program written in native rust and tests also in rust  https://github.com/Ellipsis-Labs/phoenix-v1/blob/master/tests/test_phoenix.rs


